# Convert & to &amp; in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, ampersand

I have a large `xmltype` which is not static, and in all xml nodes I need to replace symbol `&` to `&amp;` how can I do it without converting the entire xml to clob?  I need to do it only in PL/SQL.

Comment: It really does not matter how it comes, because I can not change the income of the XML, I know that it's not valid xml with `&`, so I need to fix it, because if I try to convert the xml to CLOB i get a error.

Comment: what is the error you get?